# Filtering pane issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, sharepoint-list-filter, filtermulivalue

When trying to apply a filter using the column Filter by choice, the filter pane opens to look like the screenshot below.

If the cache is cleared, it seems to revert back to normal. have also tried in different browsers (Chrome and Edge) but still happens. What is going on and how do we permanently fix it?

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of your column? Choice (with multiple selections) or lookup or something else?

Comment: Choice w multiple selections

Answer (score 0):

Compared to column filter, check the filter pane of the view to compare the results:

[image]

Comment: Using the filters pane, initially it shows options without the hashtags, but if i select See All, it goes back to looking like the list in my original post.